# How can I read SOAP-Headers and add FaultHeaders to a response sent by an AXIS 2 Web Service

Tags: soap, header, apache-axis

I have a WSDL that defines a custom SOAP-header that the client needs to send and a SOAP-Fault header that the server could send as a response.

Now I have a problem. I cannot for the life of me fathom how to set SOAP-Fault-headers on a response generated with AXIS 2 (Version 1.6.1) or read SOAP-Headers that come with a request.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If is security related you should look to Rampart.

If not, try looking into

ClientSide:
From your stub, retrieve the ServiceClient via _getServiceClient().
[enter link description here](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/api/org/apache/axis2/client/ServiceClient.html)

ServerSide:
If I recall correctly is done via MessageContext, so from axiscontext opbtain current message context.

Answer (score 0):

Add custom fault to soap response. This can be done in one of two ways.

1) Simply throwing a Java exception with a message will generate a simple Axis2 fault

Example:

```
throw new java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException("Please implement " +
        this.getClass().getName() + "#SomeOperationName");
```

Also please note:  If you generated your service using the Axis2 WSDL2JAVA utility, the line above will be added to the MyServiceName_Skeleton source for each defined WSDL Operation.

Once the .aar is deployed, connectivity to each operation can be verified using a web browser, e.g. `https://server:port/axis2/services/MyServiceName?SomeOperationName`.

2) Ensure that the WSDL defines an optional (occurs:0) custom Fault structure.  This can be sent to client with any other required (and empty) elements.

Example:

```
        com.some.service.operation.SomeOperationNameResponse_Type OPRT = new com.some.service.operation.SomeOperationNameResponse_Type();
        com.some.service.SomeOperationNameResponse OPR = new com.some.service.SomeOperationNameResponse();
        .
        .
        .           
        if ((rcStatusString.equals("Succeeded")) || (rcStatusString.equals("Warning"))) {

            <build happy path response>

        } else if (rcStatusString.equals("Failed")) {

            final MYFault fault = new MYFault();
            final MYFault_Type faultType = new MYFault_Type();
            final MYFaultList faultList = new MYFaultList();
            final MYFaultList_Type faultListType = new MYFaultList_Type();

            faultType.setFaultCode("10100");
            faultType.setFaultSubcode("9999");
            faultType.setFaultType(FaultType_Enum.SYSTEM);
            faultType.setFaultReasonText("Some Operation Failed");
            faultType.setSeverity(FaultSeverity_Enum.CRITICAL_ERROR);

            //fault.setMYFault(faultType);
            faultListType.addMYFault(faultType);

            OTHRTYPE.setAValue("");
            OPRT.setAValueType(OTHRTYPE);
            OPRT.setMYFaultList(faultListType);

        } else {
            throw new java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException(
                 "MYSERVICE: [Some Operation] Session: "+sessVal+" Request ID: "+rcRequestId+" Unrecognized Completion Status ["+rcStatusString+"]");
        }

        OPR.setSomeOperationResponse(OPRT);
        return OPR;
}
```